# Insert a form inside a jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

Friends,I want a dialog box that can accept values from the user.I have tried creating one and succeeded to an extent but the problem is that whatever i want to display in my dialog box ,it gets displayed into it as well as in my body section.Please tell me how can i display that form inside my dialog box only.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code-

```
<body>
<div id="add_dialog" title="New Entry">
  <form >
    <p>
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" /></p>
   <p> Group:<select><option value="p">p</option>
    <option value="s">s</option></select></p>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
```

My Jquery-

```
$('#add_dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0.7,
        background: "black"
    },
    buttons: {
        "ADD": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            alert("added to the list");
        },
        "CANCEL": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            alert("Select name from the list");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me

Comment: Can you tell us if you are seeing any errors

Comment: There are no errors...Its just that those input fields gets displayed on my main screen and when that dialog box pops up those field disappear from my screen and they are present inside the dialog box @SandeepNayak

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lsjx5bt/ seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:none` style to add_dialog dialog div. so that it will not appear in main screen but in dialog box it will be displayed.

```
<div id="add_dialog" title="New Entry" style="display:none;">
  <form >
    <p>
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" /></p>
   <p> Group:<select><option value="p">p</option>
    <option value="s">s</option></select></p>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ..sorry ..Thanks @JayeshChitroda

Answer (score 0):

It seems to just work fine. Make sure, you have used proper `id`

```js
$('#add_dialog').dialog({
  modal: true,
  overlay: {
    opacity: 0.7,
    background: "black"
  },


  buttons: {
    "ADD": function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      alert("added to the list");
    },
    "CANCEL": function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      alert("Select name from the list");
    }

  }


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="add_dialog" title="New Entry">
  <form>
    <p>
      Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>Group:
      <select>
        <option value="p">p</option>
        <option value="s">s</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fine and same as my code but it was displaying the form in my body section as well ..that was i wanted to solve..But now its solved ..Thanks to @Jayesh Chitroda